# Port forwarding between tp-link and mikrotik to server cant access mikrotik

Tags: networking, router, ssh, port-forwarding

My customer has this setup 
TP-Link TD-8840T (ISP connection) -> RB2011UiAS-2HnD-IN (the main router that divedes all the traffic).

The RB2011 has a ip address 192.168.1.100 (connected to tp-link device) 192.168.88.1 (gateway) and the server 192.168.88.7

I've setup a port formwarting for ssh on the RB2011 according to this tutorial http://www.icafemenu.com/how-to-port-forward-in-mikrotik-router.htm

Then when trying to connect to the router address on 192.168.88.1:22 the ssh console shows up.

I've setup a NAT on the tp link which should work the same (forwarding 22 port to 192.168.1.100:22). But cant get it to work and I don't know if this is due to the RouterOS lacking in some configuration or the tp-link device doe's not forward it further.

The RouterOS is very intimidating to me at this I've fond something called Harpin NAT tried to make the configuration but with no luck.

**partial solution**

I've made a workaround which right now is sufficient. I've setup the TP-Link device to work as a bridge.

**the above solution doesn't work after all**

It seems the problem is the Mikrotik (Routerboard) router - which can be accessed now via ssh but the port forwarding setup I've made doesn't work.

It should now forward the connection on the 2323 port to the computer with address 192.168.88.7 on port 22 (ssh port).

The forwarding is blocked for some reason. I also tried to disable all other rules that could be blocking external connections with no luck as well.

[simplified diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APmdt.png)

Comment: just to confirm.. server running ssh is 192.168.88.7 .. that server's gateway is 192.168.88.1 and that's the LAN side of the RB2011, the WAN side of the RB2011 is 192.168.1.100 ?  and the TP Link is 192.168.1.1 as the LAN address and the external IP address is X.y.y.y   (you can give the first octet like .. external ip is 74.x.x.x, this is just to get a better picture without adding confusion to the 8840T and its internal verses external IP's.  TY

Comment: Yes. the wan side od RB2011 is 192.168.1.100, the external 83.x.x.x (wan of the tp-link)

Comment: Please, please put but some form of [diagram](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) you can even use [Draw.io](http://www.draw.io) to make it. Did you could setup some kind of sniffer to see whenever packets actually reach the final host so you'd know that it's only working one way.

Comment: I've added a simplified diagram